# How to read from a file and stored data in a linked lists

Tags: java, file-io, linked-list

I am trying to read from a file and store the data into a single linked lists.

The data should have information about a user including `id` of type `long`, `name` of type `string`, and `threat level` of type `int`. Moreover, I am wondering how to read from the file and store into the linked list so that I can then do several operations.

my attempt:

**class POI**

```
public class POI {

    private long id;
    private String name; 
    private int level;

    public POI(){

    }

    public POI(long n, String s, int l){
        id = n;
        name = s;
        level = l;
    }

    public void setID (long n){
        id = n;
    }

    public void setName (String s){
        name = s;
    }

    public void setLevel (int l){
        level = l;
    }

    public long getID(){
        return id;
    }

    public String getName(){
        return name;
    }

    public int getLevel(){
        return level;
    }
}
```

**class POIList**

```
public class POIList {
    static private class Node {
        int data;
        Node next;
        Node () {
            data = 0;
            next = null;
        }
        Node(int data, Node next) {
            this.data = data;
            this.next = next;
        }
    } 

    public static void print(Node head) {
        while (head != null) {
            System.out.print(head.data + ", ");
            head = head.next;
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

    public Node insertNode(Node head, Node insertee, int position) {
        if (position < 0) {
            System.out.println("Invalid position given");
            return head;
        }
        if (head == null) {
            return insertee;
        }
        if (position == 0) {
            insertee.next = head;
            return insertee;
        }
        int i = 0;
        Node current=head;        
        while (i < position - 1 && current.next != null) {
            current = current.next;
            i++;
        }
        if (i == position - 1) {
            insertee.next = current.next;
            current.next = insertee;
        } else {
            System.out.println("Position was not found.");
        }
        return head;
    }

    static Node swapNode(Node head,
            int position1, int position2) {
        if(position1 < 0 || position2 < 0)
            System.out.println("InvalidPos");
        Node n1 = null;
        Node n2 = null;
        Node prev1=null;
        Node prev2=null;
        int maxPosition = Math.max(position1, position2);
        if (position1==maxPosition){
            position1=position2;
            position2=maxPosition;
        }
        Node temp=head;
        for (int i = 0;i <= maxPosition; i++) {
            if (temp == null) {
                System.out.println("InvalidPos");
                return head;
            }
            if (i==position1-1) prev1=temp;
            if(i == position1) n1 = temp;
            if (i==position2-1) prev2=temp;
            if(i == position2) n2 = temp;
            temp = temp.next;
        }
        temp = n2.next;
        if (prev1!=null){
            prev1.next=n2;
        }else{
            head=n2;
        }
        if (position2-position1==1){
            n2.next=n1;
        }else{
            n2.next=n1.next;
        }
        if (prev2!=null){
            prev2.next=n1;
        }else{
            head=n1;
        }
        n1.next=temp;
        return head;
    } // End of swapNode

    public static Node removeNode(Node head, int position) {
        if (position < 0 || head == null) {
            System.out.println("Invalid position given");
            return head;
        }
        if (position == 0) {
            return head.next;
        }
        int i = 0;
        Node current = head;
        while (i < position - 1 && current.next != null) {
            current = current.next;
            i++;
        }
        if (current.next != null) {
            current.next = current.next.next;
        } else {
            System.out.println("Position was not found.");
        }
        return head;
    }
}
```

**class AnalyzePOI**

```
public class AnalyzePOI {

    public static void main (String [] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException{
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        int choice;

        System.out.print("Input filename:");
        String filename = scan.nextLine();
        File file = new File(filename);
        Scanner reader = new Scanner(file);

        POIList list = new POIList();
        System.out.println("What operation would you like to implement? ");
        choice = scan.nextInt();

        switch (choice) {
        case 1 : print(list) ; 
            break ;
        case 2 : search(reader, list) ;
            break ;
        case 3 :  insert(scan, list);
            break ;
        case 4 : swap(reader, list);
            break ;
        case 5 : remove1(reader, list);
            break;
        case 6 : remove2(reader, list);
            break; 
        case 7 : output();
            break;
        case 8 :
            System.out.println ("Program Terminated");
            System.exit(0);
            break;
        }

        start(scan,file, reader );
    }

    public static void start (Scanner scan, File file, Scanner reader){
        String content = new String();
        int count=1;
        File file1 = new File("abc.txt");
        LinkedList<String> list = new LinkedList<String>();

        try {
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(new FileInputStream(file));
            while (sc.hasNextLine()){
                content = sc.nextLine();
                list.add(content);
            }
            sc.close();
        }catch(FileNotFoundException fnf){
            fnf.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("\nProgram terminated Safely...");
        }

        Collections.reverse(list);
        Iterator i = (Iterator) list.iterator();
        while (((java.util.Iterator<String>) i).hasNext()) {
            System.out.print("Node " + (count++) + " : ");
            System.out.println();
        }
    }

    public static void print(POIList list) {
        list.print(null);
    }

    public static void search(Scanner scan, POIList list) {
        int id;
        String name;

        System.out.println("Do you want to enter id or name to search for record: ");
        String answer = scan.next();
        if (answer == "id"){
            System.out.println ("Enter the id to find the record: ");
            id = scan.nextInt();
        }
        else if (answer == "name"){
            System.out.println("Enter the name to find the record: ");
            name = scan.nextLine();
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("Invalid input");
        }
    }

    public static void insert(Scanner scan, POIList list) {
        System.out.println("Enter the the location index ");
        int index = 0; 
        long p1;
        int level;
        String name;

        try {
            System.out.println("Index: ") ; 
            index= scan.nextInt() ; 
            System.out.println("ID: ") ;
            p1=scan.nextLong() ;
            System.out.println("Name: ");
            name = scan.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Threat Level ") ; 
            level=scan.nextInt() ;
        }

        catch (InputMismatchException e) {
            System.out.print("Invalid Input") ;
        }
        list.insertNode(null, null, index);
    }

    public static void swap(Scanner scan, POIList list) {
        System.out.println("Enter index 1 to swap record: ");
        int index1 = scan.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter index 2 to swap record: ");
        int index2 = scan.nextInt();
        list.swapNode(null, index1, index2);    
    }

    public static void remove1(Scanner scan, POIList list) {
        int index= 0;
        try{ 
            System.out.println("Enter ID to remove a record: ") ;
            index=scan.nextInt() ;
        }
        catch (InputMismatchException e) {
            System.out.print("Invalid Input") ;
        }

        list.removeNode(null, index) ;
    }

    public static void remove2(Scanner scan, POIList list){
        int index = 0;
        try{
            System.out.println("Enter threat level to remove a record: ");
            index=scan.nextInt() ;
        }
        catch (InputMismatchException e){
            System.out.println("Invalid Input");
        }
        list.removeNode(null, index) ;
    }
    public static void output() {

    }
}
```

Comment: I'm unsure as to what you are asking. Is your method not working? Or are you asking for some more suggestions as to improve the process

Comment: Yes the method called start is not working. I have no idea how to read a file and pass it to a linked list. The file contains a long, a string, and a integer but I don't know how to store this data types and pass them to the linked list.

Comment: Hmm. Okay. check my answer below. But, before that, I think there are some problems with other parts of your code other than the start method. I didn't go through all of it. But, don't you think the POIList class should have POI and next in the Node class rather to int and next? Where are you using your POI class for storage?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming from your question, you would like to know how to read the file that contains "String" "long" and an "int" value. Let's suppose your input file would look like this as given below.

First, we need to know how the data would look like. I'm assuming that the I/P would look something like this

```
1 OneString 10
2 TwoSTring 20
```

Now, the order I'm assuming is "long" "String" "int" with a space in between for each line. Use bufferedReader for faster reading.

```
FileReader fr = new FileReader("yourFile.txt");
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
String curLine = br.next();
while(curLine!=null)
{
String[] tempLine = curLine.split(" ");
int threat = Integer.parseInt(tempLine[0]);
String user = tempLine[1];
long ID = Long.parseLong(tempLine[2]);
addPOI(ID,user,threat);
}
```

The addPOI method would look something like this.

```
public void addPOI(long ID, String user, int threatLevel)
{
list.addAtLast(new POI(ID,user,threadLevel));
}
```

And the list can be declared something like this,

```
List<POI> list = new List<POI>();
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, but I finally found a solution of my own.